# await and async not working in Xamarin.UWP

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am using the async and await, to get the stream of the button. async method working properly, when I am using the await, it returns the function.So I am always getting the null value in the memory stream.

When I am using this (  await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(button)) operation means it returns the statement without doing the calculation.

Anyone, please suggest me how to resolve this problem?Do I need to add any other code?

This is my code:

```
 public class StreamDependencyService: IStreamDependency
{
    Button button;
    public Stream GetStream()
    {
        button = new Button() { Height = 50, Width = 50, Content = "Click" };
        return GetStream_UWP().Result;
    }
    public async Task<Stream> GetStream_UWP()
    {
        Stream memoryStream ;
        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(button);
        var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        Guid encoderId = BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId;
        using (memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(encoderId, memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels.ToArray());

            await encoder.FlushAsync();

        }
        return memoryStream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `GetStream_UWP().Result`, your code will deadlock.

Wait for the button to load first and in the Loaded event, **await** on `GetStream_UWP()`.

```
button.Loaded += async (s, e) => await GetStream_UWP();
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried still I am facing the problem. If I changed the GetStream_UWP() method to void means it worked otherwise it returns the statement when the await method comes.